# How to quickly test if two regions intercept?

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, geometry

If I randomly generated two cylinders, how do I test if they intercept? For example:

```
c1 = Cylinder[{RandomReal[1, {2, 3}]}, 1];
c2 = Cylinder[{RandomReal[1, {2, 3}] + RandomReal[{-2, 2}]}, 1];
Show[Graphics3D[{c1, c2}, Axes -> True]]
```

[image]

If I use
 `BooleanRegion[And, {c1, c2}]`

The program runs very slow if two objects have no interception.

----------------------update----------
The program still run slowly when {  } were removed from the Cylinder function, but sometimes it runs fast.

```
c2 = Cylinder[RandomReal[1, {2, 3}] + RandomReal[{-2, 2}], 1];
Show[Graphics3D[{c1, c2}, Axes -> True]]
BooleanRegion[And, {c1, c2}]
```

Comment: Removed the {} still too slow for another examples, we can test my example in my  Review.

Comment: Please unaccept the answer as it has not resolved the problem. I mentioned in my answer that it could be a bug and it seems like one.

Answer (score 6):

Calculate the distant of the two 3d objects.

```
{c1, c2} = 
  Table[Cylinder[{RandomReal[1, {2, 3}] + RandomReal[{-2, 2}]}, 1], 2];
epsilon = .0001;
intersectionQ[c1_, c2_] := 
  NMinimize[{EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, {u, v, w}], {x, y, 
        z} ∈ c1, {u, v, w} ∈ c2}, {x, y, z, u, v, 
      w}][[1]] < epsilon;
{Graphics3D[{c1, c2}, Axes -> True], intersectionQ[c1, c2]}
```

[image]

**Review**

For another example, remove the brace `{}` still too slow.

```
Clear[c1, c2];
SeedRandom[3];
c1 = Cylinder[RandomReal[1, {2, 3}], 1]
c2 = Cylinder[RandomReal[1, {2, 3}] + RandomReal[{-2, 2}], 1]
{Graphics3D[{c1, c2}], RegionDisjoint[c1, c2]}
```

Comment: I tried a few times. By removing the {}, sometimes it is fast but sometimes it is slow...No idea why.

Comment: @cvgmt, your solution performs consistently better than the built-in `RegionDisjoint`. Please file this as a bug and retag the question. For a routine calculation, a time such as 90s on a 3+GHz machine is nothing short of embarassing.

Answer (score 5):

The problem stated in OP is that for the no intersection case, it takes too long. So after some experimentation ...

I used @cvmgt 's method to generate cylinders `{c1,c2}`. Notice the three braces at the beginning and end of the endpoints. According to the docs, cylinders end points are defined as a list of lists. So I manually removed the additional pair calling those cylinders `{c3,c4}`.

[image]

The community may want to determine if this is a bug or if this is intended.